# What is the regular expression for words and numbers without spaces between them

Tags: regex

I need help building a regex to match

```
words2005
more words2005
more words 2005here
```

but not

```
words 2005
more words 2005
more words 2005 here
```

Basically I am looking for instances where people did not put spaces between their words and numbers.

For example, I am searching through text for phrases like `I was born in 1990 near Hong Kong`. Sometimes people type things in wrong and it ends up as `I was born in 1990near Hong Kong`, or `I was born in1990 near Hong Kong`. I just want to find those instances so I can fix them.

Comment: Just don't put spaces in your regular expression, and it won't match space.

Comment: So the match should have some letters and some numbers, like this: https://regex101.com/r/0Xshek/1?

Comment: You should probably add some more explanation of what you are looking for. Maybe define some rules and include more input and output examples. Based on my limited understanding, try this: https://regex101.com/r/0Xshek/2/

Comment: @degant I wish you'd put your answer back, because I liked your approach, and I like that you linked to regex101, it was a great answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, do note that it'll fully match characters followed by numbers or vice-versa. But if it's characters, then numbers, alternating (eg. `9a9`) then it'll match only partially. If you want this to work in a different way, update the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match a letter followed by a digit, or a digit followed by a letter:

```
[a-zA-Z]\d|\d[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: your simple, and correct, answer made realize my test conditions are wrong, can you also match `more words 2005here` -- that would be it. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's still very simple, you just match either condition.

Comment: In case your "words" have more than just A-Z, you could use this to find all numbers that specifically don't have a *space* before/after: `[^ ]\d+|\d+[^ ]`.

Comment: LOL. Thank you for your answer @Barmar. I totally overthought this and was trying to exclude white spaces, match alphanumerics etc... Your answer works exactly as I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: `[^ \d]\d+|\d+[^ \d]` (added `\d` to the before/after terms).

Answer (score 1):

To get any words containing both alphabets and numbers, you could use:

```
[A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[A-Za-z]+
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Xshek/3/)

```
// Will match completely:
words2005
1990near

// Will only match parts of 
9gag9
f4f
```

**Alternate:**

If the requirements were to match an alphanumeric string containing atleast one alphabet and atleast one number, then this would be a better regex:

```
(?:[A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[A-Za-z]+)[A-Za-z\d]*
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Xshek/4/)

```
// Completely matches 
9gag9
f4f
text929number123
```